# Why couldn't the men's Man taste like watermelon?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, behaalotcha-parsha, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

The verse says in Parshas Beahaloscha ([Numbers 11:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.11.5?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.11.5.2&lang2=bi)):

> זָכַ֙רְנוּ֙ אֶת־הַדָּגָ֔ה אֲשֶׁר־נֹאכַ֥ל בְּמִצְרַ֖יִם חִנָּ֑ם אֵ֣ת הַקִּשֻּׁאִ֗ים וְאֵת֙ הָֽאֲבַטִּחִ֔ים וְאֶת־הֶחָצִ֥יר וְאֶת־הַבְּצָלִ֖ים וְאֶת־הַשּׁוּמִֽים׃
>
> We remember the fish that we used to eat free in Egypt, the cucumbers, the melons, the leeks, the onions, and the garlic.

And [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.11.5?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Numbers.11.5.2&lang2=bi) comments (based on the Midrash and the Gemara in Yoma):

> "את הקשאים" - אמר ר' שמעון מפני מה המן משתנה לכל דבר חוץ מאלו מפני שהן קשים למניקות אומרים לאשה אל תאכלי שום ובצל מפני התינוק משל למלך וכו' כדאיתא בספרי
>
> את הקשאים THE CUCUMBERS — R. Simeon said, “Why did the manna change its flavor into that of anything one wished (as the Midrash states) except into these vegetables here mentioned, the taste of which it appears not to have assumed since the people lusted for them? Because they are injurious to nursing mothers. So indeed people say to a woman: Do not eat garlic and onions on account of the baby. A parable! This may be compared to a king, etc. as it is related in the Sifrei Bamidbar 87.

So this explains why pregnant women's Man didn't taste like watermelon. But what about the rest of the Jewish people? Why coudn't their Man taste like watermelon?

Comment: According to Yoma 75a one opinion is with the 5 foods listed, the people tasted their flavor but not their texture...https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.75a.10?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Answer (score 8):

I heard in the name of the "Balei Mussar" that Hashem made it so that no one should be able to taste these items 1) so that it shouldn't be so hard for the women who can't eat it, and 2) to teach everyone to always think about another Jew's hardships.

I heard this a while ago; I don't remember the name/names of those who said it. Now I found this idea - at least part of it - in ספר מנחת חיינו on Chumash pg 283[image: ספר מנחת חיינו on Chumash pg 283].